# Error in Device Manifest: HAL Compatibility and Deprecated HALs

Tags: android, vi, tr

I am trying to compile AIDL following the guide mentioned here: https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_41678668/article/details/129916032?utm_source=app&app_version=5.13.0&code=app_1562916241&uLinkId=usr1mkqgl919blen

My source is Android 13 for RPI4, which can be found at: https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/AOSP13/?fbclid=IwAR2ZMR13L4UxhmaKM3tLaHpHRTqCSfTszcc-UO2D3uu38g1MHKbtvFRTLDw

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ZzS.png)

However, when I run "make -j4", I encounter the following error, even though I have tried modifying manifest.xml and compatibility_matrix.7.xml in out/target/product/rpi4/system/etc/vintf/.

The error is only resolved for android.hardware.media.c2/v4l2 and /ffmpeg.

What should I do to fix this issue?